# Density of complex polynomial in the space of entire holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\int_\mathbb C f(w)e^{\frac{-|w|^2}{2}} \overline {p(w)} dA(w)=0$ for all complex polynomial $p(w)$. Then show that $f=0$.

Anyone could please help me for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $dA(w)$ is Lebesgue two-dimensional Lebesgue measure on the complex plane?  And part of the hypothesis is that the integrand is in $L^1$ for this measure, for all polynomials $p$?

Comment: polynomials are dense in Fock space see zhu book

Comment: Polynomials are **not** dense in continuous functions on a compact set that has nonempty interior.

Comment: ya i should erase that idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we will proof that the family $(z^n)$ are an orthogonal basis of your space
so if $ n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ :
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle z^m, z^n\rangle &=& \int_\mathbb{C}z^{m}\bar{z}^n e^{-|z|^2/2}dA(z)\\
&=& \int_0 ^\infty   r^{m+n+1} e^{-|r|^2/2}dr\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i\theta( m-n)}d\theta\\
&=& a_{m,n} \delta_{m,n}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\delta_{m,n}$ is kronecker symbol, so $(z^n)$ are orthogonal.

to see that they will be totale, given $f$ holomorphic in your space,
and $n  \geq  0$, we have
$$
\langle f, z^n\rangle = \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{|z|\leq R} f(z) \bar{z}^{n} e^{-|z|^2/2}dA(z)
$$ 
Since the Taylor series
$$f(z) =
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
a_kz_k$$
converges uniformly on $|z| < R$, we have

$$
\int_{|z|\leq R} f(z) \bar{z}^{n} e^{-|z|^2/2}dA(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty
a_k\int_{|z|\leq R} z^k \bar{z}^{n} e^{-|z|^2/2}dA(z)=
a_n\int_{0\leq r \leq R} r^{2n+1}  e^{-r^2/2}dr
$$

Using polar coordinates, so :
$$\langle f, z^n\rangle =a_n\int_{\mathbb{C}} |z|^{2n}  e^{-|z|^2/2}dA(z)
$$
Therefore, the condition that  $\langle f,z^n\rangle=0$ for all $n\geq0$ implies that $a_n= 0$ for all
$n\geq 0$  which in turn implies that $f = 0$. This shows that the system $(z^n)$ is complete
.

Comment: However, the question was about $\int f(z) p(z) \; e^{-|z|^2} \; dA(z)$ rather than $\int f(z) \overline{p(z)}\; e^{-|z|^2}\; dA(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

While you probably meant the question to which Hamza gave an answer, the answer to the question you wrote is **no**.

Let $f(z) = z$.  Note that with $z = r e^{i\theta}$, $dA(z) = r \; dr \; d\theta$, so for integer $n \ge 0$,
$$ \int_{\mathbb C} f(z) z^n e^{-|z|^2/2} dA(z) = \int_0^1 r^{n+2} e^{-r^2} dr
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n+1)\theta}\; d\theta = 0$$
And thus for any polynomial $p(z)$, $$\int_{\mathbb C} f(z) p(z) e^{-|z|^2/2} dA(z) = 0$$

Comment: you have right a have a big mistake here with the inner product